# How to return admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in Firebase Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am experiencing an error when returning an admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to the client from an https callable cloud function.

This is how I am returning:

```
const date = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

// ... uploading date to firestore ...

return date;
```

But, when I get it in the client side, the date is an empty object

> {}

I have tried to convert the date to millis before returning in order to avoid problems with JSON serialization, but .toMillis() is not a function (because I haven't retrieved the date from Firestore)

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: See the duplicate, you are using the `serverTimestamp()` method to read while it should only be used when you write

Answer (score 1):

As I am using Google Cloud Function (running in Google Servers),

`new Date()` is equals to `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

so, I have changed the code to this:

```
const date = new Date();

// ... uploading date to firestore ...

// Return date in millis in order to avoid problems with https serialization
return date.getTime();
```

And now is working as expected!